# Creating a variable within Object in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to populate an ArrayColletion of Objects and I have the following code:

```
var objeto:Object = new Object;

for ( var index:int=0; index < modeloHojaEnvio.modelo.arrayDatos.length; index++) {
    if ( modeloHojaEnvio.modelo.arrayDatos.getItemAt( producto ).productoID == modeloHojaEnvio.modelo.arrayDatos.getItemAt( index ).productoID  &&
        modeloHojaEnvio.modelo.arrayDatos.getItemAt( producto ).destinoID == modeloHojaEnvio.modelo.arrayDatos.getItemAt( index ).destinoID ) {

        objeto.("lento"+precio)     = modeloHojaEnvio.modelo.arrayDatos.getItemAt( producto ).precio_base80;
        objeto.("rapido"+precio)    = modeloHojaEnvio.modelo.arrayDatos.getItemAt( producto ).precio_base100;

        modeloHojaEnvio.modelo.arrayDatosForDatagrid.addItem( objeto );
    }
}
```

Here is where I'm confused: **objeto.("lento"+precio)**, due to i do not know how many "lento" variables will be generated, so I want to link the number to be like this: **objeto.lento1**, **objeto.lento2**, and so on.....

Thanks.

Comment: You need to create several different objects, give them name and add them or?

Comment: It's best if you use a vector to better maintain consistency.

Comment: The question is that I need to link these data with a Datagrid, so columns numbers is variable and that's why I need to generate within the same object different variable names. labelField must be linked with a variable from the Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace with:
`objeto["lento"+precio]`